# jQuery get id of child with class name '...'

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need foo to be the id of the one child under #ele (excluding the first child) that has BlahClass assigned to it

```
var foo = $('#ele').children('.BlahClass:not(:first)').attr('id');
```

?

Comment: looks fine to me. what's the problem?

Comment: Is it a child, or a descendant of #ele.

Comment: @KevinB  it's a child.

Comment: @jbabey. ...it returns undefined. I can see I have other problems here... Thanks

Comment: @user3024007 then your code works as-is. http://jsfiddle.net/69NUE/

Comment: There's nothing really wrong with the selector, so it probably doesn't match the markup, but as we have no idea what the markup looks like, that is impossible to answer ?

Comment: @adeneo. I needed to make sure my syntax was ok on that line. Resolving this issue is another story

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you question correctly, and you want the second element with 'BlahClass' then this should do it:

```
var foo = $('#ele').children('.BlahClass:nth-child(2)').attr('id');
```

Comment: I meant ANY child, except 1st. Looks like my syntax was ok but other things are broken